# How to create a new col in txt file base on other two col

Tags: r, file, loops

Let's say I have txt file with this information

```
   exons affected_exon
    24  22
    37  7
    14  7
    33  3

So what I want to do is to create a new col called splicing like this:
exons affected_exon splicing
        24  22   midle
        37  7    middle 
        14  14   last
        33  1    first
```

So for splicing I want the follow:

```
if affected_exon = 1 -> complete with first
if affected exon = exons -> complete with last
if affected exon < exons (and > 1) -> complete with middle
```

For the moment I have this code in R, but is not working and I can't figure out why:

```
out <- read.delim("out.txt", sep = "\t", header = T)
  scans <- out$exons
  exon <- out$affected_exon
  cluster <- out$group 
  for (i in out ){
    if (scans == exon){
    cluster <- c("last")
    }
    if (exon == 1){
    cluster <- c("first")
    } 
    if (exon < scans & exon > 1){
    cluster <- c("middle")
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't see the difference.. could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: What is `Total_number_exons` it is not in your example.

Comment: edited, is exons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommand to read it as a `data.table`:

```
data_set = data.table::fread("out.txt", header = TRUE)
```

Then you can set for all:

```
data_set[, cluster := "middle"]
```

And change it for last and first:

```
data_set[affected_exon == 1, cluster := "first"]
data_set[affected_exon == exons, cluster := "last"]
```

You can write it:

```
data.table::fwrite(data_set, "textfile.txt", sep = "\t")
```

Hope it helps